# How to add another column in where clause

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am having issue trying to figure out how to add another column to my where clause not sure how to do it. I need it to have FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME since the existing database has two columns.

```
   <?php



    header('Content-Type: application/json');


    try {

    $dbName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\fpdb\\staffing.mdb";
     $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $Employee_Name=  trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);       
            $params = array( ':FIRSTNAME' => $Employee_Name);

    $query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM tbl_USERS
        WHERE FIRSTNAME=:FIRSTNAME");

    $query->execute($params);

    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $EMPLOYEE_NUMBER=trim('EMPLOYEE_NUMBER');
    $rc= $result[$EMPLOYEE_NUMBER];

    echo json_encode ($rc);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Employee_Name=  trim($_POST["Employee_Name"]);       
        $params = array( ':FIRSTNAME' => $Employee_Name, ':LASTNAME'=>$Employee_Lastname );

$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM tbl_USERS
    WHERE FIRSTNAME=:FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME=:LASTNAME");
```

I'm guessing the column names above but generally the right idea

Comment: I tried that the only issue is my script does not work because I think lastname as Employee_Lastname. Is there a way to get my script to use both?

Comment: I am going to mark it right because the question was not asked with the script so I should go ahead and ask another question

Comment: You would need to post the lastname in your ajax call. I assume that the HTML element is a select menu item. How is that populated initially? Can you show a snippet of the dropdown ?

Comment: oh it has to be a drop down user would not be able to type it in

Comment: can you provide a snippet of the dropdown or explain what the value of each option contains? Does the value contain ONLY the employee name? Is that forename and surname?

Comment: the value only contains Employee_Name

Comment: I posted the snippets of both textboxes above and the script code. I will later turn it into a dropdown trying to see it will work

Comment: ok - so the user could enter their full name? ie: john Smith - in which case split the supplied employee_name data and post forename and surname in your ajax call

Comment: yes they have to supply full name but I may change it to get it from the db as a dropdown but the first and last name is still in the db seperate not as one column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71281/discussion-between-veronica-and-ramraider).